# How can I make a button apply a class to the next div in the document flow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use jQuery to have a button that moves you through a series of steps by bolding each one in succession. I also want each step to be bolded when clicked on, and unbolded when any other step is clicked on. So, it needs to know which step is already bolded, and then bold the next one when the button is clicked. I am new to jQuery and don't know how to word this!

This is my html:

```
<div id="container">

  <div id="step1">
    1. Step 1.
  </div>

  <div id="step2">
    2. Step 2.
  </div>

  <div id="step3">
    3. Step 3.
  </div>

  <div id="step4">
    4. Step 4.
  </div>

  <div id="step5">
    5. Step 5.
  </div>

  <button>
    NEXT STEP
  </button>
```

and this is my css:

```
#container {
  height: 90%;
  width: 60%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 5% 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

button {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -8px;
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 8px;
}

div {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

And this is the jQuery I've tried to start (just for clicking steps to bold them):

```
$(function() {

  $("#step1").click(function (){
    $("#step1").addClass("bold")
  })

  $("#step2").click(function (){
    $("#step2").addClass("bold")
  })

  $("#step3").click(function (){
    $("#step3").addClass("bold")
  })

  $("#step4").click(function (){
    $("#step4").addClass("bold")
  })

  $("#step5").click(function (){
    $("#step5").addClass("bold")
  })

})
```

It also seems pretty repetitive to have a separate function for each step. Is there a way to combine them all? I tried but then clicking one step bolded all the steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a class of `step` to each step element, I think this should meet your requirements:

```js
    $('.step').click(function(){
      $('.bold')
        .removeClass('bold');
      $(this)
        .addClass('bold');
    });

    $('button').click(function(){
      if( $('.bold').length < 1 ){
        $('.step')
          .first()
            .addClass('bold');
      }
      else {
        $('.bold')
          .removeClass('bold')
            .next('.step')
              .addClass('bold');
        if($('.bold').length < 1){
           $('.step')
             .first()
               .addClass('bold');
        }
      }
    });
```

```css
#container {
  height: 90%;
  width: 60%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 5% 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

button {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -8px;
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 8px;
}

div {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="step1" class="step">1</div>
  <div id="step2" class="step">2</div>
  <div id="step3" class="step">3</div>
  <div id="step4" class="step">4</div>
  <div id="step5" class="step">5</div>
  <div id="step6" class="step">6</div>
  <div id="step7" class="step">7</div>
  <div id="step8" class="step">8</div>
  <button>Next Step</button>
</div>
```

[JSBIN](https://output.jsbin.com/cayimeluyu)

Update: include remove all button:

```js
     // To bold a step when it is clicked,
     // first remove any existing bold class,
     // then bold the step that was clicked
    $('.step').click(function() {
      $('.bold')
        .removeClass('bold');
      $(this)
        .addClass('bold');
    });

     // To bold the next step when next button is clicked:
     // If there are no bold steps, bold the first one
    $('.next').click(function() {
      if ($('.bold').length < 1) {
        $('.step')
          .first()
          .addClass('bold');
      }
      // If there are bold steps, remove the current bold class, add bold class to the step after it
      else {
        $('.bold')
          .removeClass('bold')
          .next('.step')
          .addClass('bold');

        // If there weren't any steps after the bold classes were removed, add bold class to the first step
        if ($('.bold').length < 1) {
          $('.step')
            .first()
            .addClass('bold');
        }
      }
    });

     // To remove .bold classes from all steps
    $('.reset').click(function() {
      $('.bold').removeClass('bold');
    });
```

```css
#container {
  height: 90%;
  width: 60%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 5% 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
/* 
      .clear to fix the buttons problem.
      Watch out when you use float: left
      or float: right.
    */

.clear:before,
.clear:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}
.clear:after {
  clear: both
}
.next,
.reset {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -8px;
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 8px;
}
.reset {
  background: hsl(349, 86%, 50%);
  margin-right: 10px;
}
div {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.bold {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="step1" class="step">1</div>
  <div id="step2" class="step">2</div>
  <div id="step3" class="step">3</div>
  <div id="step4" class="step">4</div>
  <div id="step5" class="step">5</div>
  <div id="step6" class="step">6</div>
  <div id="step7" class="step">7</div>
  <div id="step8" class="step">8</div>
  <div class="clear">
    <button class="next">Next Step</button>
    <button class="reset">Reset</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this got it! Now I'm wondering if there can be another button that removes the bolding from any step? I tried to mess around with the code, but I still don't understand how this works yet. Can you explain how to do that?

Comment: No problem. I added comments to the jQuery code in my updated answer, should help you proceed further. Have a good one.

Comment: I have another challenge if you're interested... I want to add a class to a step when another specific step is highlighted.

Comment: Exactly. You've done it again! I was so stuck. I just had no idea how to search for the syntax I needed!

Comment: No worries. It'll become second nature with more practice and tinkering.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your after?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container [id]').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('bold');
  });
  $('#container button').click(function () {
    $('#container [id]:not(.bold):first').addClass('bold');
  });
})
```

```css
#container {
  height: 90%;
  width: 60%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 5% 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

button {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -8px;
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 8px;
}

div {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

  <div id="step1">
    1. Step 1.
  </div>

  <div id="step2">
    2. Step 2.
  </div>

  <div id="step3">
    3. Step 3.
  </div>

  <div id="step4">
    4. Step 4.
  </div>

  <div id="step5">
    5. Step 5.
  </div>

  <button>
    NEXT STEP
  </button>
  
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the greatest advantages of using jQuery is abstraction. You don't need to be so specific. Event handlers attached to a jQuery selector will apply to each element returned by the selector.

```js
$('.step').click(function () {
 $('.step').removeClass('bold')
 $(this).addClass('bold')
})
```

```css
#container {
  height: 90%;
  width: 60%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 5% 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

button {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -8px;
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 8px;
}

div {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

  <div class ="step" id="step1">
    1. Step 1.
  </div>

  <div class ="step" id="step2">
    2. Step 2.
  </div>

  <div class ="step" id="step3">
    3. Step 3.
  </div>

  <div class ="step" id="step4">
    4. Step 4.
  </div>

  <div class ="step" id="step5">
    5. Step 5.
  </div>

  <button>
    NEXT STEP
  </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would do away with the id's and do it with classes but to keep it as close to your code as  possible - Add a count to the next button and use that to apply the class to the div (you can increment the count on the onclick). Also using a count (over the other methods described in the other answers) allows you to reset the count back to the first div.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#nextStep').click(function(){
    var current = $(this).val()
    makeBold(current)
    })
  
 $('#container div').click(function(){
   var current = parseInt($(this).attr('id').substr(-1))-1;
     makeBold(current);
  })
})

function makeBold(current){
    var next = parseInt(current) +1;
    var total =  $('#container div').length;
    if(current == total){next = 1};
  
    $('#nextStep').val(next);
    $('div').removeClass('bold');
    $('#step'+next).addClass('bold');
  
  }
```

```css
#container {
  height: 90%;
  width: 60%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 5% 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

button {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -8px;
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 8px;
}

div {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

  <div id="step1" class="bold">
    1. Step 1.
  </div>

  <div id="step2">
    2. Step 2.
  </div>

  <div id="step3">
    3. Step 3.
  </div>

  <div id="step4">
    4. Step 4.
  </div>

  <div id="step5">
    5. Step 5.
  </div>

  <button id="nextStep" value="1">
    NEXT STEP
  </button>
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to add in the code that Damon added below that allows you to click on the steps to highlight them as well? And then have the nextStep function take it from there? I tried adding it but I think your codes conflict somehow.

Comment: yup - give me a minute - will amend answer

Comment: no worries - but for the sake of completeness - have a look at what I did - bascially clicking the individual divs or the next button passes that current number ot a named function that adds the .bold class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this demo:

```js
$(function() {

  $('div[id^="step"]').on('click', function(){
   $(this).addClass('bold');
  });
  
  $('button').on('click', function(){
   $('div[id^="step"]').not('.bold').first().addClass('bold');
  });

});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 90%;
  width: 60%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 5% 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

button {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -8px;
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 8px;
}

div {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

  <div id="step1">
    1. Step 1.
  </div>

  <div id="step2">
    2. Step 2.
  </div>

  <div id="step3">
    3. Step 3.
  </div>

  <div id="step4">
    4. Step 4.
  </div>

  <div id="step5">
    5. Step 5.
  </div>

  <button>
    NEXT STEP
  </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code,

```js
$(function() {

  $('#buttonNextStep').click(function (){
    var step = parseInt($(this).data('step') || '0');
    $('#step' + (step).toString()).removeClass('bold');
    $('#step' + (++step).toString()).addClass('bold');
    $(this).data('step', step);
  });

});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 90%;
  width: 60%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 5% 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

button {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -8px;
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 8px;
}

div {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

  <div id="step1">
    1. Step 1.
  </div>

  <div id="step2">
    2. Step 2.
  </div>

  <div id="step3">
    3. Step 3.
  </div>

  <div id="step4">
    4. Step 4.
  </div>

  <div id="step5">
    5. Step 5.
  </div>

  <button id="buttonNextStep">
    NEXT STEP
  </button>
  </div>
```